# Do strace have debug symbols?

Tags: gdb, debug-symbols

```
[root@xxx~]# which strace
/usr/bin/strace
```

I want to debug how it actually works,but can't find its debug symbols,where is it?

Answer (score 1):

Programs shipped in Linux distributions do not usually have debug symbols in the executables (they are sometimes in a separate file that can be downloaded).  You can get the source code [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/), though, and compile it with debug symbols.